# Center element in groupbox C#

Tags: c#, center, groupbox

I've created window applications and would like to center elements in the groupbox. Can I do this with a code?

[groupbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ClIyA.png)

Comment: Winforms is quite terrible with things like that. You can probably use a table layout panel inside the group box with 3 columns, and keep all the elements inside the middle cell. Please note that a table layout panel cell can only contain a single control, so you must use another panel inside it.

Comment: WinForms or WPF? This would be easy in WPF.

Answer (score 0):

This code assumes you will be creating the additional controls entirely in code and not using the Designer.
If you do use the Designer, just remove the line

> Button button = new Button() { Text = "Button1" };

and put the name of the button control in the next line.

```
    private void AddControlsToGroupBox()
    {
        Button button = new Button() { Text = "Button1" };
        CentreControlInGroupBox(this.groupBox1, button);
    }

    private void CentreControlInGroupBox(GroupBox theGroupBox, Control theControl)
    {
        // Find the centre point of the Group Box
        int groupBoxCentreWidth = theGroupBox.Width / 2;
        int groupBoxCentreHeight = theGroupBox.Height / 2;

        // Find the centre point of the Control to be positioned/added
        int controlCentreWidth = theControl.Width / 2;
        int controlCentreHeight = theControl.Height / 2;

        // Set the Control to be at the centre of the Group Box by
        // off-setting the Controls Left/Top from the Group Box centre
        theControl.Left = groupBoxCentreWidth - controlCentreWidth;
        theControl.Top = groupBoxCentreHeight - controlCentreHeight;

        // Set the Anchor to be None to make sure the control remains
        // centred after re-sizing of the form
        theControl.Anchor = AnchorStyles.None;

        // Add the control to the GroupBox's Controls collection to maintain 
        // the correct Parent/Child relationship
        theGroupBox.Controls.Add(theControl);            
    }
```

The code also assumes you will place only a single control in the Group Box. I don't think you will find it too hard to adjust the sample accordingly if there are multiple controls.